# Java Restlet framework: long going requests return after 60s

Tags: java, timeout, client-server, httpclient, restlet

Using org.restlet framework (with camel-restlet 2.12.3 but without camel) on the server side - everything works fine, but while waiting for requests which take longer than 60s the server seems to just return after 60s even though the request is still being worked on.
Here is how the server is started:

```
Restlet router = (Restlet) oSpring.getBean("ImportHandlerRouter");
Component component = new Component();
component.getServers().add(Protocol.HTTP, iPort);
Context context = component.getContext().createChildContext();
FilterJsonp jsonp = new FilterJsonp(context);
jsonp.setNext(router);
component.getDefaultHost().attach(jsonp);
component.start();
```

Debugging shows that the `handle` Restlet method is called again after 60s and the stack seems to show that it was a normal request, but I'm quite sure that the client doesn't actually re-request after 60s (testing client with completely different servers with longer requests works fine).
Is seems like some system property or socket property or something similar, but I'm struggling with finding out where exactly to set those.

Any idea on how to prevent the forced server's response after 60s?

UPDATE:
This seems to only happen while starting from Eclipse - starting in TOMCAT as separate WAR the calls are blocking.

Comment: Where is the Restlet code actually deployed? Servlet container or standalone HTTP server?

Comment: The code you see is executed in a MainApp.java directly from Eclipse. In production it is deployed in TOMCAT some servlet there. But I'd like to first fix the Eclipse version. Or is it also auto-using some kind of servlet i.e. Jetty or something?